# Fib Generator answer; Can't pass arguments in a function if it's functioning as an iterable?

Tags: python-3.x

First off, sorry for the unclear question, I didn't know how else to address this. Here's a Fibonacci code I wrote using a generator, but somehow I'm getting a `NameError: name 'n' is not defined.`

```
def fib_g(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while counter <= n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


for i in fib_g(n):
    print(i)


print(fib_g(3))
```

so I changed things around and tried

```
def fib_g(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


counter = 0
for i in fib_g(n):
    if counter <= n:
        print(i)
        counter += 1

print(fib_g(3))
```

but I still get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\fibonacci.py", line 20, in <module>
    for i in fib_g(n):
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: your variable 'n' is not defined anywhere in code that is the issue of getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a rather silly question now that I look at it again a few hours later, but here's the answer to my question.

> "Can't pass arguments in a function if it's functioning as an iterable?"
>   **Of course you can!**

If functions can be used as an iterable, there is no reason why functions *with arguments* can't be (they are still functions nonetheless!)

### Reason for the NameError

The reason for the `NameError` then, was simply as Python said: `'n' is not defined`. How could that be? Didn't I write `print(fib_g(3))` at the end? The problem was that the `for` loop runs before that line. (silly mistake I know...)

### Motivation for being able to run the code by running an external  print statement

If you wanted someone to be able to run the `fib` code easily without having to find the exact line to edit the code, or maybe if someone was importing your fib code and you don't want them to edit it directly, it will be useful if n could be defined outside of the code. In that case, this is what the code should look like:

```
def fib_g(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


def fib_g_print(n):
    counter = 0
    for i in fib_g(n):
        if counter <= n:
            print(i)
            counter += 1


fib_g_print(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following program will help you to find the Fibonacci series. You dont need to have the extra for loop in their.

```
n = input('enter the length of the fib series? :')

num = int(n)
fib = []

#first two elements
i = 0
j = 1

count = 0

while count < num:
    fib.append(i)
    k = i + j
    i = j
    j = k

    count+=1

print(fib)
```

Edit:

Problem with your code is that your going into Never ending loop in your function. Also, your iterating with generator with variable n which is undefined. Modified your code little bit. Please refer the code below.

```
def fib_g(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    x = 0
    while x < n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
        x+=1

for i in fib_g(10):
    print(i)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: good answers but not exactly what I was confused with, I've posted a response myself but still upvoted with thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a valid argument to `fib_g` instead of `n`, which is a parameter to be used only inside the scope of `fib_g`. Also you should initialize `counter` and increment it inside the `while` loop:

```
def fib_g(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    counter = 0
    while counter < n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
        counter += 1

for i in fib_g(10):
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```